# Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I was trying to creating Bar Charts for my data in CSV file. I used the following code [[based on this tutorial]](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/):

```
topics <- read.csv("test.csv")
data <- structure(list(T1= as.numeric(topics$T1), 
                       T2 = as.numeric(topics$T2),
                       T3 = as.numeric(topics$T3), 
                       T4 = as.numeric(topics$T4),
                       T5 = as.numeric(topics$T5),
                       T6 = as.numeric(topics$T6),
                       .Names = c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5","T6"),
                       class = "data.frame"),
                       row.names = c(NA, 6L))
attach(data)
print(data)
dput(head(data))
colours <- c("red", "orange", "blue", "yellow", "green","black")
barplot(as.matrix(data), main="My Barchart", ylab = "Numbers", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, col=colours)
legend("topleft", c("First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth","Sixth"), cex=1.3, bty="n", fill=colours)
```

I could not solve this error:

```
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The `dput(head(data))` shows that the data has been read successfully !! but the error still exist.

Comment: Code is not reproducible

Comment: what do you mean by code is not reproducible?

Comment: It means we can't copy and paste your code into our R console and get your error (we don't have `topics`).  We need to be able to do that in order to help you.  It's covered in [mcve]

Comment: it works but with error on my side !!

Comment: Of course it does.  You have the `topics` data set.  We don't.  It would be better if you just used the result from `dput(data)` as the assignment for `data`. Debugging questions need to be reproducible. Did you read the link above?

Comment: This is the result of dput(head(data))
`structure(list(T1 = c(0.24, 0, 0, 0.04, 0.04, 0), T2 = c(0, 0.3, 
0, 0, 0, 0), T3 = c(0.04, 0.04, 0, 0.24, 0, 0), T4 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0.04, 0.33, 0.04), T5 = c(0, 0.09, 0.21, 0, 0, 0), T6 = c(0, 
0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0.34)), .Names = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", 
"T6"))
`

Comment: Try replacing `as.matrix(data)` with `as.matrix(as.data.frame(data))` in `barplot()`

Comment: It gives the same error `Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rightly suggested by [Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven), you must replace `as.matrix(data)` with `as.matrix(as.data.frame(data))`.

You can try this code as well:

```
colours <- c("red", "orange", "blue", "yellow", "green","black")
data2 <- data.frame(data)
barplot(as.matrix(data2), main="My Barchart", ylab = "Numbers", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, col=colours)
legend("topleft", c("First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth","Sixth"), cex=1.3, bty="n", fill=colours)
```